# Migration angular 1.4 to angularjs 1.5 make error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I start to learn angularjs whit this simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.1/mootools-  yui-compressed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='assets/js/menuMatic.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/posts.js"></script>
<script src="js/service/post.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',  {templateUrl:'partials/home.html',controller:'PostsCtrl'})          
            .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

when i use angularjs 1.2.27 it's work fine but when i use angularjs 1.5.8 it show me this error

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]  angular.js:38
```

i believe it some global controller function is disabled or something but i don't know how to fixed
**EDIT**

I use angularjs version 1.4.8 and it's working .. but when i use 1.5.8 it not working anymore

Comment: What is the full error? How are you defining your `PostsCtrl` controller? Do any of your other JS files (`posts.js`, `post.js`) accidentally redefine your `myApp` module by using `angular.module('myApp', <anything here at all>)`?

Comment: @MateuszSip that is completely incorrect

Comment: to start with, you should use `angular.js` rather than `angular.min.js` when troubleshooting.  It *seems like* you might have done that, since the error you posted references `angular.js` even though the code you posted doesn't.  beyond that, it is hard to create a working example to test your problem, as you haven't shown the contents of all the files (posts.js, post.js, etc...).

Comment: in fact, using your code **exactly as written**, and supplying a dummy controller for the missing `posts.js` code, this works without error (other than missing assets not relevant to the question).  http://plnkr.co/edit/VdKGds8NAU4snXvgNmYU?p=preview.  It seems more likely than ever that your problem lies in one of the code files you haven't provided here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separately add $rootProvider to your config like below:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',  {templateUrl:'partials/home.html',controller:'PostsCtrl'})          
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
}]);
```

Comment: This would only be the case if OP was minifying their JS code

Answer (score -2):

It's either you put **semi-colon** at the end of the first line.

Or remove the "**app**" in second line of code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',  {templateUrl:'partials/home.html',controller:'PostsCtrl'})          
            .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

**or**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',  {templateUrl:'partials/home.html',controller:'PostsCtrl'})          
            .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

Comment: have you tried to put jquery library before declaring angular.min.js

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. JavaScript's ASI takes care of separating the first line from the second as independent statements